# In SQL, can't set a binary to 1

Tags: php, mysql, sql

I have created a table in MySQL with a binary field name 'active' and set to NULL by default.

But when I want to update it with this command:

```
$update_users = $bdd -> query("UPDATE users SET `active` = 1 WHERE `id` = '$data1' LIMIT 1") or die(mysql_error());
```

The field is updated to 31 ! and not to 1.

I have also tried

```
SET `active` = true
```

but same result.

p.s: I have set 'active' using phpMyAdmin interface (no SQL statement), but here are the values of this field: Type => binary(1), Null => yes, Defaut => NULL

Comment: Can you also post how you defined `active`?

Comment: i notice something wrong in your code : you use `mysqli` to query the database (`$bdd->query()`) and `mysql_error()`. you cannot mix `mysql_xx()` and `mysqli_xx()`

Comment: Why do you have quotes on field name?

Comment: @Kostis It doesn't change anything if I put quotes or not.

Comment: @Crozet Ok, so what function should I use instead of `mysql_error()` ?

Comment: mysqli has the same function : http://php.net/manual/fr/mysqli.error.php

Comment: Is it `31` or `0x31`? I tend to believe it's the second option.

Comment: @axiac 0x31 = 49 in decimal...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`0x31` == `49` is the [ASCII code](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/ASCII#Printable_characters) of character `'1'`.

The value is stored in the column but, [because of its type](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.7/en/binary-varbinary.html), it is returned in a special format: each byte from the value is displayed in its hexadecimal representation (2 uppercase [hex digits](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Hexadecimal)). Depending on the MySQL client you use, the `0x` hexadecimal prefix may or may not be present in the output.

As the [documentation](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.7/en/binary-varbinary.html) explains, the `BINARY` type contains strings (similar to `CHAR` types). That's why the numeric value you want to insert (`1`) is handled as a string and it becomes the character `'1'`).

In order to store the number `1` into a `BINARY` column you have to store the character `'0x01'` in it:

```
UPDATE users SET `active` = 0x01 WHERE `id` = '$data1' LIMIT 1
```

Or you better use the `TINYINT` type instead.

Answer (score 1):

I think you are confusing `BINARY`. According to the [documentation](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.7/en/binary-varbinary.html):

> The BINARY and VARBINARY types are similar to CHAR and VARCHAR, except that they contain binary strings rather than nonbinary strings. That is, they contain byte strings rather than character strings. This means they have the binary character set and collation, and comparison and sorting are based on the numeric values of the bytes in the values.

From looking at your question I assume what you really want is something like a boolean value (0 or 1) and not binary data.

In this case either use `TINYINT(1)` or `BIT(1)`.